# R: Can't parse files due to Timeout problem

Tags: r, parsing

I have a dataframe with source names and links. These links give me access to databases that I need to download.

I сreated a parser that downloads files into a directory with a corresponding source name:

```
options(timeout = 10^12)

parse_db <- function(links,
                     begin = "data_raw/",
                     end = ".db",
                     pref = "export-",
                     suf = links_table$source,
                     n = 65){
  for (i in 1:n) {
    download.file(url = links[i],
                  destfile = str_c(begin, paste(pref, suf[i], sep = ""), end, sep = ""),
                  mode = "wb")
  }
}
```

R downloads first 11 links and then says that it cannot reach next link (`Can't open the URL...`) and the serever's time is out. I wonder why does this problem occur beacause I've set the global timeout options.

What am I doing wrong? May be it is possible to set a sleep time (or increase the timeout) for each iteration?

Comment: Can you post the links file? Does it always timeout on the 12th link?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that. The answer for the second question is yes, also asked a colleague to do the same thing and she faced the same problem.

Comment: Do you have permission to do this from the server's owner?

Comment: @Roland you mean the permission to download files?

Comment: Permission to do this automatically. Some server owners allow manual downloads but don't allow or limit automatic downloads. If that's the case, there are usually technical measures in place to enforce this.

Comment: To see if it's an issue with just that one, you could remove it from the list temporarily and see if the code runs fine on the rest.